# Is there any solutions that help casadi MX variable to be used in pytorch nn.conv1d(convolution)?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, casadi

I now have a Sequential Neural Network which is used for predict robot states. But I have a problem when implementing the NN into Casadi to solve an MPC problem. The error keeps warning me that I can not use Casadi MX variable in a Sequential NN which requires convolution process.

I have seen the repo [l4casadi](https://github.com/Tim-Salzmann/l4casadi) but it seems only supporting nn.linear but not nn.conv1d. Hopes to find a solution here and thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L4CasADi supports PyTorch Models exceeding linear layers (such as convolutions). L4CasADi supports all PyTorch Models, which are jit traceable/scriptable.

L4CasADi Example with Convolution:

```html
import torch
import numpy as np
import l4casadi as l4c
import casadi as cs


# Create a model with convolutional layers
class ConvModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.conv1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3, padding=1)
        self.conv3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 64, 3, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(64 * 7 * 7, 128)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(128, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(-1, 1, 7, 7)
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = x.view(-1, 64 * 7 * 7)
        x = torch.nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


x = np.random.randn(49).astype(np.float32)
model = ConvModel()
y = model(torch.tensor(x)[None])
print(f'Torch output: {y}')

l4c_model = l4c.L4CasADi(model, model_expects_batch_dim=True)

x_sym = cs.MX.sym('x', 49)
y_sym = l4c_model(x_sym)

f = cs.Function('y', [x_sym], [y_sym])
y = f(x)

print(f'L4CasADi Output: {y}')
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. I almost spent a week writing the convolution myself. Your answer definitely helps me a lot.